# Is it possible to add more hard disks to RAID10 while keeping it online?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, dell

I have RAID10 configuration with 6 HDD running on Dell PowerEdge 1950 via Powervault MD1000.
I want to add two more hard drives to the array so the initial RAID10 will turn to one with 8 HHDs.
Is it possible without rebuilding the whole array and losing all the data on it?

Comment: Your question and title are inconsistent. Do you simply want to retain the data or do you also want to keep it on-line, meaning you want to add the drives without powering down?

Comment: +1 Good question.  I would think it would work very similar to the way you expand a Raid 5 array on a poweredge, which is done while online, but I'm curious to see an answer from someone who has tried.

Comment: to John Gardeniers,
I want to add two more drives to RAID10 array without restart or data loss. Restart less critical but data loss is.

Comment: I hope you mean data loss is inconvenient and not actually "critical" ^^

Comment: It depends on the RAID card you're using - can you add that to the question description?  The 1950 can come with a few different cards, and the exact steps will vary on the card.

Comment: I use PERC6/E card, this is the only way to connect MD1000 to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be possible, using OMSA. go into the raid controller configuration, and look for a drop down box that has the "reconfigure" option under the logical disk that is your raid10

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted. I didn't see "reconfigure" option under the logical disk. And DELL support told me that "Spanned virtual disks such as RAID 10, 50, and 60 cannot be reconfigured"

Answer (score 2):

i believe your server raid controller has Online Capacity Expansion feature- check your documentation.

Comment: That wasn't an RTFM, he told him exactly what to look for in the docs.

Comment: I agree with phoebus -- the key to look for here is "online capacity expansion", a feature that most enterprise hardware RAID controllers provide.

Comment: andrws and John Röthlisberger, maybe my question was wrong. I know that on the paper you can do that but my question was from your experience not about ability... sorry for misleading question.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember, when Adding disks to RAIDs (online or not) it's a good idea to add one drive at a time, let the RAID to its thing and then add the next. I had a server halfway offline for two days while the raid rebuilt after adding two 500GB disks into a RAID5 array. Good thing I did it on a friday afternoon...

Your RAID should be extendible online, but double-check your backups anyway, before starting.

Note to self: Must thoroughly read question. Sorry.

Comment: In raid 10, you add capacity with pairs of drives at a time.

Comment: Which doubles the the time to have both HHDs online

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I was recently researching the same subject and need to expand a raid 10 with two additional drives.  Unfortunately the definitive answer at this time is no.

This is an excerpt from the Dell Controller manual:

"An online virtual disk can be reconfigured in ways that expands its capacity
and/or change its RAID level. Spanned virtual disks such as RAID 10, 50, and
60 cannot be reconfigured."

Answer (score -1):

You cannot expand Raid 10 (50 & 60) without redoing the array.

Comment: Can you indicate why?  Some controllers have the ability to do this including many Dell controllers.